# Why does my Toyota 3L engine won't idle and makes a metal scratching noise?

Tags: toyota, diesel, idle, land-cruiser

My Toyota Land cruiser manual transmission has just had the engine reconditioned: new pistons, piston rings, engine block, cylinder head, fuel injectors, fuel injector pump head, starter, fuel filter.

But now it won't idle and needs to be helped to stay on by pulling the accelerator cable manually. And it's making a metal scratching noise.

What different solutions should I try to solve the issue ?

Comment: Is this the KZ turbocharged diesel?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Has the fuel system been purged completely?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, it's not the KZ turbocharged diesel. It's a Land Cruiser Prado 90 series 3L engine manual transmission.

Comment: No, the fuel system hasn't been purged completely

Comment: I just did the complete purge of the fuel system and it ran for about 3minutes non stop. Then I heard a squeaking noise coming from the engine block probably, Then it turned off abruptly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Has the engine got oil in it?

Comment: Yes, it has oil. That was the first thing I checked too

Comment: It sounds like it seized up. You say it has oil, but does it have oil pressure? How are you verifying it does?

Comment: I removed the engine valve cover and turned the car on. And as the camshaft was rotating, oil was being splashed everywhere. Maybe that's a good sign that the engine might not be seized up. What should I check next?

Comment: Are you saying that after the engine ran for 3 minutes then stopped, you were able to turn the engine over using the starter motor?

Comment: Yes the engine was able to start again after the purge of the fuel system as mentioned earlier, but It started making this very uncomfortable noise. Worth mentioning that as it was running with the valve cover off, there was smoke coming out of the cylinder head. What should I do?

Comment: The engine shakes a lot though and with a loud noise like two metals rubbing against each other, but I have to hold the accelerator cable or else it loses power and turns off.

Comment: It is probably normal for fumes to come out from where the valve cover goes, this would normally be sucked back into the air intake by the PCV system.  So the engine won’t restart?

Comment: The smoke is normal then, ok thanks. Why does the engine loses power if I don't hold the accelerator cable to help it? And where could the metal scratching noise be coming from?

Comment: Positive side is that the starter works, and the fuel system as well. But on the negative side the engine can't idle, and makes this metal scratching noise. Any help?

Comment: After a deeper diagnostic, I found out that the metal scratching noise was due to a bad crankshaft bearing. It was completely crushed inside the engine block cylinder. And one of the piston cooling nozzle was broken too. It was a very big deal after all and it's going to be very expensive to repair too.

Comment: I'm going to have the crankshaft repaired, get new bearings for both the crankshaft and connecting rod, a new oil filter as I suspect some metal fragments have fallen inside, another connecting rod since the old one was damaged by the frictions, a piston cooling noozle. Thanks all for your precious comments.